# Rails - Contextual validations based on state

Tags: validation

Let's say there is a post model like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  .......
  .......
end
```

It has two attributes **:title** and **:body**.

Now a Post object can go through multiple stages: **'draft'** -> **'published'**.

Now while saving a post in drafts mode, the **:title** isn't required. But while saving it in published mode, it needs to have a presence validation on the title:

```
validates_presence_of :title
```

Now, what is the best way to do this in Rails? I think some implementation of a decorator pattern would be great, wherein in a controller, I would dynamically add validations to an active record object.

This is a simplified version of a bigger problem I have. In the actual case, there are a lot more validations including those done on associated objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) for your state transitions, it supports just what you are looking for, with examples in the readme file.

Otherwise, all rails validations have optional `if` paramter. If, for example, your post has a `published?` method that returns whether it's in a published state, you could write `validates_presence_of :title, if: :published?` and have it do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) for states. May be it's time to switch to state_machine :)

Comment: Don't rush to switch just yet - state_machine is more popular, but doesn't seem to be actively developed any more.

Comment: Oh right. Another thing, in my case, I would have to validate associated models as well during state change, how would I do that?